# Site names need to be run through HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() before output on Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

In both the [private](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/cv/edit/171909) and [public view](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/dannybeckett)s of my CV on Careers, ***Unix & Linux*** shows as ***Unix &amp; Linux***:

[image]

The site names need to be passed to `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` before output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed and will go live with the next push sometime this afternoon.