# Site names mangled in close reason

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, close-reasons, site-name

[image]

As you can see, Genealogy & Family History.SE's generic close reason distorts the site name. The `&amp;` hasn't turned into `&`.

Related bug: [Site names need to be run through HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() before output on Careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178453/192187)

Comment: That's my error, Luke, not a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include an ampersand in the default off-topic reason without any problems - the system escapes it automatically.

However, if you go back and *edit* the reason again, you're shown the escaped ampersand (`&amp;`) - if you then save it, that gets escaped *again* (`&amp;amp;`) and shows up incorrectly.

The work-around is just to make sure the close reason looks correct before you save it.